# What is the Catholic Teaching on intellectual property?

Tags: catholicism

Does the Catholic Church have specific teaching on Intellectual Property rights (I’d appreciate specifics and coverage of copyright, patent, and trademark), and is this teaching binding on the faithful?

Comment: @M__ that’s not incredibly helpful because there is not a given definition within that verse of what is Caesar’s or what is God’s.